# Non empty string in search:search in Marklogic 8

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to search using NOT and I did the following

```
"((collection:Concept) AND ((species:(*)) AND ( - species:(Homo sapiens))))"
```

This works fine, but this returns all the species which are empty or have blank string.. Is there a better way to do this ? I want to avoid in my search results empty string species or blank species..

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by simply not having a species element in your document if that element would be empty. That is, instead of this:

```
<doc>
  <species/>
  <other-info>...</other-info>
</doc>
```

do this:

```
<doc>
  <other-info>...</other-info>
</doc>
```